# Checking if a directory is ready System.IO.Directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, io, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to check if a driver is ready?

Since I am listing all directories, when it reach the dvd for example, I get an exception saying that the driver is not ready.

Thanls a lot

```
@{
try
{
    //Resgata todos os drivers Lógicos do Sistema
    string[] drives = System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives();

    Response.Write("<ul class=\"jqueryFileTree\" style=\"display: none;\">\n");

    //Itera sobre cada driver no array
    foreach(string drive in directoryEntries) {


        //Para cada driver cria um LI A 
        Response.Write("\t<li class=\"directory collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" + drive + "\">" + drive + "</a></li>\n");

        //Resgata subDiretórios de cada driver
        string[] directoryEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(drive); 
    }


}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the DriveInfo.IsReady property.

```
  DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

  foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
  {
      if (d.IsReady == true)
      {
         // do something
      }
   }
```

Further information can be found on this MSDN entry:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2